# Easy way to return an iterator content and increment it

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, copy

I want to create a method which return a token and increment this one.

I did this:

> _tokens is an std::istream_iterator

```
std::string             getToken()
{
  std::string           result;

  result = *_tokens;
  ++_tokens;
  return result;
}
```

As you can see this is kinda ugly cause I am returning a copy of a copy.

But I cannot return a reference on result cause result is a local variable.

And I cannot get the reference on *_tokens cause ++_tokens will change the content.

Have you got any idea how I could do this in a better way ?

Comment: Well, you can use an in-reference parameter, if you cannot have move semantics. Otherwise you should be able to do something like `return *_tokens++;` and hope for RVO.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the following

```
std::string             getToken()
{
  return *_tokens++;
}
```